# NVD3 - Adding and resizing multiple vertical lines to stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to add multiple vertical lines to the stacked area chart.

Adding multiple lines was achieved using a for-loop (maybe not the best way). The problem is, for-loop did not seem to work when updating the lines with `nv.utils.windowResize()` --- only the last line was updated eventually.

Maybe this could be done in a more D3 way without using a loop? [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/road2stat/fwewqc1a/4/) for reproducing the problem (line 207 - 235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd re-write your custom lines to be a little more `d3`-ish in nature (use data-binding, no explicit loops, etc...)

```
var xgrid = [1166996800000, 1186996800000, 1216996800000];

// add vertical lines
var custLine = d3.select('#stackedbarchart')
  .select('.nv-areaWrap')
  .append('g');

 custLine.selectAll('line')
  .data(xgrid)
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr({
      x1: function(d){ return chart.xAxis.scale()(d) },
      y1: function(d){ return chart.yAxis.scale()(0) },
      x2: function(d){ return chart.xAxis.scale()(d) },
      y2: function(d){ return chart.yAxis.scale()(1) }
  })
  .style("stroke", "#000000");
```

And then the update becomes:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
  chart.update();
  custLine.selectAll('line')
    .transition()
    .attr({
      x1: function(d){ return chart.xAxis.scale()(d) },
      y1: function(d){ return chart.yAxis.scale()(0) },
      x2: function(d){ return chart.xAxis.scale()(d) },
      y2: function(d){ return chart.yAxis.scale()(1) }
    });
});
```

*Note* the use of the transition in there so the lines move a little better with the re-draw of the chart.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwewqc1a/6/).

Comment: - thanks so much! The additional transition effect looks great! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a for-loop to do this, just use `selectAll`.  Here's one way:

First, to select the vertical lines easily I assigned them an id called vlines, in the for-loop on line 210

```
.attr('id', 'vlines')
```

Then use selectAll with this id to update the lines on resize.  Here's your updated resize function:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
  chart.update();
   d3.selectAll('#vlines')
    .attr('x1', function (d,i) { return chart.xAxis.scale()(xgrid[i]); })
    .attr('y1', function (d,i) { return chart.yAxis.scale()(0); })
    .attr('x2', function (d,i) { return chart.xAxis.scale()(xgrid[i]); })
    .attr('y2', function (d,i) { return chart.yAxis.scale()(1); });
 });
```

Using `selectAll` and functions, you can easily avoid loops in most cases.

Comment: It works, thank you! `selectAll` is really useful, guess I have to learn more about D3 basics...